# Find second to last word in multi-lined string array

Tags: java, string

I need to find second to last word in each line (they are divided by space) and find 3 most popular of them and find how many are there? Can you help me in any way?

Input example:

```
abcd i
asd ffdds abcd ddd ?
abcd ffdds asd ddd i
ddd abcd i
a f g w e a asdfasdasdas fdd i
```

Answer that I need:

```
abcd 2
ddd 2
fdd 1
```

or

```
2 abcd
2 ddd
1 fdd
```

This is my code

```
public class asdf {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        String str;

        List < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
        while ((str = in .readLine()) != null) {
            if (str.startsWith(" ") && str.endsWith("i") || str.endsWith("?")) {

                list.add(str);
            }
        }
        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]); //for backup
        String[] stringArrAC = list.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < stringArrAC.length; i++) {
            stringArrAC[i] = stringArrAC[i].substring(63);
        }
        //String[] stringArrLAST = (new String[0]);
         Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap();
        for (String line : stringArrAC) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            String nextToLastWord = words[words.length - 2];
            occurrences.put(nextToLastWord, 
                    occurrences.get(nextToLastWord) == null 
                            ? 1 
                            : occurrences.get(nextToLastWord) + 1); 
        }

        occurrences.entrySet().stream()
            // Sort the values in descending order
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            // Gets top 3 entries
            .limit(3)
            // Print them 
            .forEach(System.out::println);
        try {
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < stringArrAC.length; i++) {
                pr.println(stringArrAC[i]);
            }
            pr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("No such file exists.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this problem youre trying to solve part of a larger problem? In other words, what is the goal driving this search for code?

Comment: This is it.. final stage...

Comment: Alright. Sometimes a wacky request like this is part of something bigger. Just trying to clarify for other users who may in fact be able to help you. My solution would be to get each line, split on spaces or some kind of separator char, and get the second to last element of array. Your logic for counting the highest ones should be easy if develop a collection of the words and how many times theyve been seen.

Comment: Well thats my idea also.. but i have no idea how to do it...

Comment: Well.. i will go to sleep... its 0515 hrs in the morning in my country.. will check later in day. :)

Comment: When you see this later: check out the split method on strings. See if that helps.

Comment: I fixed typos, improved the title and formatted the code for better readability. I updated tags to remove irrelevant tags. The closing braces don't match in your code there is a missing `}`. Please fix it.  Make sure to proofread your questions before you post to avoid typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 makes this simpler.
Count the occurrences of the next to last word with a HashMap, then use streams to sort the HashMap in descending order and grab the top three values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList() {
        {
            add("abcd i");
            add("asd ffdds abcd ddd ?");
            add("abcd ffdds asd ddd i");
            add("ddd abcd i");
            add("a f g w e a asdfasdasdas fdd i");
            add("123 awef bad");
            add("123 awef bad");
            add("123 awef bad");
            add("oneword");
        }
    };

    Map<String, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap();
    for (String line : lines) {
        // Skip blank lines
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }

        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        // Account for a line that might have only one word
        String nextToLastWord = words.length >= 2 ? words[words.length - 2] : words[0];
        occurrences.put(nextToLastWord,
                occurrences.get(nextToLastWord) == null
                        ? 1
                        : occurrences.get(nextToLastWord) + 1);
    }

    occurrences.entrySet().stream()
            // Sort the values in descending order
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            // Gets top 3 entries
            .limit(3)
            // Print them 
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Results:

```
awef=3
ddd=2
abcd=2
```

Comment: looks like this is it... will report back if i succeeded

Comment: Cant get it to work... java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 keeps comming up on for  String nextToLastWord = words[words.length - 2]; if i implement it in my code..

Comment: @Eiseps Update your question with the code you've tried. Also, is there a line that has just one word?

Comment: @Eiseps Is there a line, in your array, that has only one word?

Comment: Shortest is "15169 i" ... oh damm it.. there is an empty line at the end.. would that be that problem?

Comment: @Eiseps One word, meaning there are no spaces. However, the blank line could be causing the issue also.

Comment: hmm.. cant seam to get that blank line out.. :\ but there is no line with "one word" in it.. so the blank line must be the problem.. it must..

Answer (score 0):

Parse each line with a string tokenizer to get an array of words. For each line, the word you want will be the second to last element in the array. Create a Map to store the word in, along with an associated counter that you'll increment by one each time you encounter the same word. In other words, once the word is in the map, if you find that word again, increment its counter in the map. When you're done, get the key value pairs from the map, find the 3 highest counter values, and their associated words.